# FFT correct absolute and relative power fomula

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am applying FFT to multiple time series (EEG channels) and calculating the magnitudes of each freq bin using `20 log10(r*r + i*i)`.

To plot a head surface such as the image, I take the average of magnitudes at each point and interpolate. The plot is coming out but I am not sure about the scaling and how to differentiate between absolute and relative power?

[image]
Is there an easy formula to follow?

Comment: The output magnitude of the FFTs are going to be based on the input amplitudes of the time series data. Do you know if these data time series are normalized relative to one another? If not, it is difficult to say there is any one formula to achieve that normalization.

Comment: time series data is not normalized relative to one another, however, they are amplified and maybe passed through a filter to be noise free.

Comment: I will use the following formula:

For absolute power: take the average of frequency bins per each electrode and scale logarithmically (log10(power)) to convert to dB

For relative power: take the average of frequency bins per each electrode and divide either by total power or the number of bins.